# Models list as choices in a Model

Tags: django, django-models

Hello there I'm working on small personal project for fun and I need to have all models as choices in a field in a model, I made a function to get all models names:

```
def get_models():
    choices = [ct.model_class().__name__ for ct in ContentType.objects.all()]
    return choices
```

and my Model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False, blank=False, choices=lazy(get_models, list)())
    act = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, choices=ACTIONS_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.config

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('model', 'act'),)
```

But when I run the code I have this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I tried to get the models differently using:

```
from django.apps import apps
models = apps.get_models()
```

But I had the same error again, what I did understand is that I'm trying to get the models before that Django can load them, my question is: is there any way to work around this issue? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

Your field `model` should be a foreign key to the `ContentType` model, Django will then render the field as a select box with all models available

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried both, for the first case I still have the same error (models not loaded), and for the second I have this error: 'Action' object has no attribute 'fields', btw I'm using Django 1.10

Comment: I misread your question, I thought you were doing this in a form. Why not use a `ForeignKey`? `content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)`

Comment: This solution is correct but not generically applicable, so I wish to add to it.  If the model in question is in a different database than the content_type field, then cross-foreign key relations are not possible, so it would need to be a positive integer field with choices, but that yields the AppRegistryNotReady error, so in that case, you would need to override the admin form and set the choices there instead of in the model.  It is an edge-case, but it does exist.